# R2dbc cannot instantiate Class using empty constructor

Tags: java, reactive, r2dbc

I have ran into a complete stop trying to develop a service using R2dbc. I am building an integration test for it. The service has a huge problem, which while preparing the test data in the integration test I am able to to build, save it in db (h2) and receive the test data from h2 db for entity user.

Sadly when I call the endpoint I am trying to test where data for user has been saved while setting up the test data for user, there in a service class r2dbc fails to instantiate User class while trying to get the object from db. I have defined an empty constructor for User. I am completely stuck at understanding why this instantiation fails. When setting up the test data in the integration test I am able to save and receive rows, but when the integration test reaches the endpoint and the service it just returns the following error while querying:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.x.base.domain.User using constructor com.x.base.domain.User() with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:240)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.map(Flux.java:6091)
    io.r2dbc.h2.H2Result.map(H2Result.java:67)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
```

The entity:

```
@Table("user")
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
    User() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column("id")
    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotNull
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column("login")
    private String login;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column("last_name")
    private String lastName;
    ....
    (getters and builder down below)
}
```

I have debugged the instantiation to a really low level and have not yet seen anything to cause this error. The DB is found and also the reflections (I do not use setter classes).

The integration test:

```
// here user is defined and populated - I only use block in the integration tests.
var user = userRepository.create(user).block();
// here I test if the method in the service should work
var userByLogin = userRepository.findOneByLogin(user.getLogin())

 TreeDTO treeDTO = webTestClient
            .get()
            .uri("/api/x/x/" + user.getId())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk()
            .expectHeader()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .returnResult(TreeDTO.class)
            .getResponseBody()
            .blockFirst();
```

Service method, where the instantiation fails:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Mono<DevelopmentTreeDTO> getTreeByUserId(String userId) {
        return SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin()
            .flatMap(login -> userRepository.findOneByLogin(login) -> error is thrown here (user is authenticated and login is present in securityUtils)
                         .map(user -> { ...
```

I tried to keep it as short as possible, but I just am scratching my head with this. Any recommendation is extremely welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just checking, that package private constructor isn't the reason, perhaps? Does it help if you make it `public`?

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but that does not make a difference